# How to use super() when subclassing Tkinter widgets?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, super

Trying to create Tkinter window using `super()`.
I get this error:

```
TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not classobj
```

Code:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('200x150')
    app = Application(root)

    root.mainloop()

main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Tkinter` uses old-style classes. `super()` can only be used with [new-style classes](http://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/).

Comment: So what I should do is to do this: **tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)** instead of super()?

Answer (score 11):

While it is true that `Tkinter` uses old-style classes, this limitation can be overcome by additionally deriving the subclass `Application` from `object` (using Python multiple inheritance):

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame, object):

    def __init__(self, master):
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('200x150')
    app = Application(root)

    root.mainloop()

main()
```

This will work so long as the Tkinter class doesn't attempt any behaviour which requires being an old-style class to work (which I highly doubt it would). I tested the example above with Python 2.7.7 without any issues.

This work around was suggested [here](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/880604). This behaviour is also included by default in Python 3 (referenced in link).