# Passing class values to another class using Tkinter in Python 3.5

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, tkinter

I have the following code (example of my real program):

```
from tkinter import *
def class1(Frame)

    def nv(self,x):
        self.vent=Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app=class2(self.vent)
        self.value=x

    def __init__(self,master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master=master
        self.frame=Frame(self.master)
        self.btn=Button(self, text="example", command=lambda: self.nw(1))
        self.btn.pack()
        self.pack()

def class2(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master=master
        self.frame=Frame(self.master)
        self.value=class1.nw.value.get()
root= Tk()
marco=Frame(root)
marco.pack
lf=class1(marco)
root.mainloop()
```

this last part is the problem, i cant use .get() properly for this problem, I want to get the value of x when I create the new window.
I use lambda so i can execute the command with parameters.
So the question is, is there a way for me to access the value of x in class 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be quite confused about the usage of classes when using `tkinter`. `super()` should not be used with tkinter as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171328/python-2-7-super-error) and when declaring a class you should use the `class` keyword, not `def`. `.get()` is a method of a `tkinter` variable class such as `tkinter.IntVar`, `tkinter.StringVar`, etc. so is not needed in the example you have given.

What you need is the function in the `Frame` you are trying to get the value of x from (`nv`) and then parse that value to the `__init__` method in the child `Frame`.

Here is my solution:

```
from tkinter import *

class Class1(Frame):

    def nv(self,x):
        self.vent = Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = Class2(self.vent,x)

    def __init__(self,master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.master = master
        self.btn = Button(self, text="example", command=lambda: self.nv(1))
        self.btn.pack()
        self.pack()

class Class2(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, x):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.master=master
        self.frame=Frame(self.master)
        self.x_text = Label(self, text=str(x))
        self.x_text.pack()
        self.pack()

root = Tk()
marco = Frame(root)
marco.pack()
lf = Class1(marco)
root.mainloop()
```